# Is it OK to synchronize touch events and updates in an Android game?

Tags: android, synchronized, touch-event, game-loop

So the game works fine and all but I have noticed that in extremely rare circumstances the app crashes in random places. I did my debugging and my theory is that because touch events on the surface are handled in the app's UI Thread and the game updates happen in a separate thread (looping thread or whatever it's called), these two are stepping on each other's feet. My solution was to synchronize the touch events on the surface:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized (this.gameLoopingThread) {
        //Handle touch events here
        return true;
    }
}
```

with the game's updates in the looping thread:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (this.running) {
        synchronized (this) {
            doUpdate();
        }
        doDraw();
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering, is it OK for me to do this? I'm not great yet on multi-threaded apps so someone please tell me if this solves my problem since I can't really verify because the issue doesn't happen often enough (has happened only twice). And if so, shouldn't we do this on every game we implement? Tutorials I have seen everywhere online never do this. Is there a reason?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized does help to lock the threads updating methods to the touch events, that is how i implemented my game as well. I notice it is stable when synchronized both ways, while only one leaves it unstable.